# Value are showing different results

Tags: swift

can anybody explain why this below code is showing different values

```
class ABC: UIViewController

    {
        var Distance : Int!

        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            var obj_A = ABC()
            obj_A.Distance = 10
            var obj_B =  objVR_A
            obj_A.Distance = 30

            print(obj_A.Distance) // 30
            print(obj_B.Distance) // 30

            var x = 10
            let y = x
            x = 30
            print(x) //30
            print(y) //10
    }}
```

Why the value of Obj_B is 30 while value of Y is 10.

Thanks.

Comment: integers are values types, and classes are reference types. This is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

**From Apple documentation:**

```
// Reference type example
class C { var data: Int = -1 }
var x = C()
var y = x                       // x is copied to y
x.data = 42                     // changes the instance referred to by x (and y)
println("\(x.data), \(y.data)") // prints "42, 42"
```

Copying a reference implicitly creates a shared instance. After a copy, two variables then refer to a single instance of the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is because primitives are value-based types, and classes are reference-based. You can find detailed explanation on [Apple's blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10).

```
// Value type example
struct S { var data: Int = -1 }
var a = S()
var b = a                       // a is copied to b
a.data = 42                     // Changes a, not b
println("\(a.data), \(b.data)") // prints "42, -1"



// Reference type example
    class C { var data: Int = -1 }
    var x = C()
    var y = x                       // x is copied to y
    x.data = 42                     // changes the instance referred to by x (and y)
    println("\(x.data), \(y.data)") // prints "42, 42"
```

Comment: Ideally, an answer will include at least a summary of the link it provides, so that if the link goes dead, there'll still be an explanation of the main details.